# Tensorflow Serving models from key/value store?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I have a large number of dynamically generated models that I would like to serve with Tensorflow serving, but it seems that TF serving can only pick up models from local file paths?

Is there a way to serve from from a key/value store like Redis or DynamoDB?

I could use something like S3FS to mount models locally from S3, but I question the reliability and performance.

Comment: Are you using docker to host your models??

Comment: Yep, we are using Docker.